# Use different versions of referenced DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

Somehow I've been lucky and never had to deal with this problem, even though I think it's a common one:

I've got a web project, let's call it `SomeProject`. `SomeProject` has a reference to a 3rd party library, let's call it `SomeThirdParty`, version 1.0. `SomeProject` also has a reference to a home-grown class library, let's call it `SomeLibrary`. `SomeLibrary` also has a reference to `SomeThirdParty`, but a different version (let's say 2.0).

Version 1.0 and 2.0 of `SomeThirdParty` share most of the same signatures, but are different implementations. I need `SomeProject` to use the 1.0 implementation, and `SomeLibrary` to use the 2.0 implementation if possible.

I compile `SomeProject` using its reference to log4net. The DLL that ends up in the bin directory is the one that `SomeProject` references. At runtime, when code from `SomeLibrary` runs, it attempts to execute the code from version 2.0 of `SomeThirdParty`, and of course fails, throwing a `FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '`SomeThirdParty`, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=[etc.]' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Obviously I could upgrade `SomeProject` to the newer DLL or downgrade `SomeLibrary` to the older DLL, but it wouldn't be ideal for many reasons.

I think the right answer involves installing SomeThirdParty in the GAC, but I'm not sure exactly how I'd go about doing this, and how it would affect other developers and servers.

Any suggestions you may have are appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting both versions of SomeThirdParty into GAC should do what you want. Use gacutil utility or Start->Run->assembly then drag-n-drop.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. I really don't want to go this route, since it would mean the assemblies would have be installed in the GAC on all of our developers' machines, and all of the servers, and any incoming developer. But I'll keep this in mind if we can't find an alternative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From my answer earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576769/2367343

I ran into this yesterday for visual studio web developer using Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

My solution,

right click your project (*.csproj) and edit it.

Right underneath:

```
<PropertyGroup>
```

Place

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Then rebuild your solution. You must separate the two version dlls into two different directories in your project when including them (required).

I did

```
ora11 >> Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Version 11)

ora9 >> Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Version 9)
```

Doing this allows your IDE to use both versions of DLLs.