# C# .Net Dll References Dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, nuget

I have written a DLL library **MyLIB.dll** (version *1.0.0*) that depends on the third party  DLL library **OtherLIB.dll** (version *1.0.0*). Library **OtherLIB.dll** is available on the NuGet and I'm adding it to the **MyLIB.dll** project via NuGet package manager.

Now let's say that I'm writing a new application, say **MyAspNetMvcApp** and I'm adding **MyLIB.dll** (version *1.0.0*) to it via NuGet. It automatically adds **OtherLIB.dll** (version *1.0.0*) as it depends on it. Everything is working fine, but...

After a month there is being released a new version of **OtherLIB.dll** - version *1.0.1*. I'm updating it via NuGet.

Now, My ASP.NET MVC application stops working because there is being thrown an exception by **MyLIB.dll**. It expects **OtherLIB.dll** in version *1.0.0* but there is already newer version being used.

In **MyLIB.dll** project references I can see that "Specific Version" flag for **OtherLIB.dll** is being set to "False", so I have no idea what's going on here...

Is there any possibility to solve this issue in other way than by providing assembly binding in web.config file? How can I add a reference to **OtherLIB.dll** for **MyLIB.dll** in such way that there will be no exception when I update **OtherLIB.dll** to a newer version?

Comment: Sounds like you're suffering from DLL Hell. Have you through deploying some of these DLL's to the global assembly cache (GAC)?

Comment: You question is a little vague. If you don't want to use v1.0.1 of **OtherLIB.dll**, why did you update your MVC solution?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use v1.0.1. I want to use the most recent version of **OtherLIB.dll**, but I don't want to release a new version of **MyLIB.dll** each time when a new version of **OtherLIB.dll** is released. I don't want users of my library to have a problem when they update **OtherLIB.dll** via NuGet manager.

Comment: @GrantByrne - I don't want to add it to GAC or anything like that, as both of these libs are supposed to be available only on NuGet and to be as simple to use as possible.

Comment: That makes more sense. Take a look at the NuGet documentation regarding versioning for dependencies located [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning#Specifying_Version_Ranges_in_.nuspec_Files).

Comment: Actually the problem is related to the dll itself not NuGet package. Even if I setup NuGet package of **MyLIB.dll** to always depend on the most recent version of **OtherLIB.dll** it will not help me. I would even say that it would be more problematic as it would download a version of **OtherLIB.dll** that is not supported by **MyLIB.dll**. Anyway I have found that there are two additional references in **MyLIB.dll** project that have "Specific Version" set to "True". I hope that this is an issue. I will check it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this yesterday for visual studio web developer using Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

My solution,

right click your project solution (*.csproj) and edit it.

Right underneath:

```
<PropertyGroup>
```

Place

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

Then rebuild your solution. You must separate the two version dlls into two different directories in your project when including them (required).

I did

> ora11 >> Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Version 11)
>
> ora9  >> Oracle.DataAccess.dll (Version 9)

Doing this allows your IDE to use both versions of DLLs.

Comment: Actually it won't help. In my case **MyLIB.dll** depends on **OtherLIB.dll** that is available on NuGet (and is being downloaded from it). Hence there is no way to "embed" it into **MyLIB.dll**.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your `MyLIB.dll` is set to use a specific version of `OtherLIB.dll`. Go into your `MyLIB` project and click on the reference to `OtherLIB.dll`. Check the properties to see if "Specific version" is set to true.