# NLog dll is not being copied over to consuming application from Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dependencies, nlog

I am using class library as a reference to many applications. I have Nlog dll (4.5.3 for .Net Framework 4) being referenced in a class library through Hierarchy folder structure.
For example "D:\current\Bin\NLog.4.5.3\lib\net40-client". Somehow NLog dll is not being copied over to consuming application's bin folder and I am getting "System.IO.FileNotFoundException".

I made sure that Copy to Local is True(See attached NLog properties). I also applied false to it and again made it true as suggested in some other posts, but it did not work. Any suggestions on it?

Another thing which I don't understand is - I do have NLog 1.0.0.505(NLog for .Net 2) in "D:\current\Bin\" path. If I change NLog dll to 4.5.3 in mentioned path, Then it brings it over Nlog dll to consuming applications.

Though in my class library, there is no reference of parent path NLog dlls. But my class library dll files reside in "D:\current\Bin\" path and all applications are consuming it from here. Is there any possibilities that application is not going further down hierarchy for NLog dll and just keep checking limited to parent bin Hierarchy? Even though if I remove NLog dll(For .Net framework 2.0) from "D:\current\Bin\" path, it is not picking up NLog from Hierarchy path.

Class library and applications are both built on .Net framework 4.0
[image: NLog DLL Properties in referenced library]

Exception - An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in class library.

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Why do you think Nlog.dll should be found if it's not in the same directory as your application? The framework will not search subfolders for a dll. Make sure it's in the bin folder and you should be fine (and use only one Version of Nlog in your project, otherwise things get really complicated).

Comment: PMF - I think when Class library is being used in consuming applications, Nlog dll should be copied over from Subfolder to consuming application's Bin folder. I do have another projects which are using previous Nlog. So, I could not afford to change the existing structure. Any thoughts to debug the problem ?

Comment: If you really need two versions of nlog.dll in the same folder, it really gets complicated. You can use the application or library manifest to redirect links to different library versions, but that's an advanced topic. See i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132652/use-different-versions-of-referenced-dll for possible solutions. To keep the code maintainable in the future, I would rather take the time and update the other projects as well.